# React native project not starting on android

Tags: android, react-native, google-play-services

> java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No static method
>   checkHandlerThread(Landroid/os/Handler;Ljava/lang/String;)V in class
>   Lcom/google/android/gms/common/internal/Preconditions; or its super
>   classes (declaration of
>   'com.google.android.gms.common.internal.Preconditions' appears in
>   /data/app/tv.ampz-xq0syKD7zk1lwewrOmiHaw==/base.apk!classes35.dex)
>           at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.GmsClientEventManager.onConnectionSuccess(Unknown
>   Source:20)
>           at com.google.android.gms.common.api.internal.zaaw.zab(Unknown Source:292)
>           at com.google.android.gms.common.api.internal.zaak.zaaq(Unknown
>   Source:125)
>           at com.google.android.gms.common.api.internal.zaak.onConnected(Unknown
>   Source:105)
>           at com.google.android.gms.common.api.internal.zabe.onConnected(Unknown
>   Source:101)
>           at com.google.android.gms.common.api.internal.zaq.onConnected(Unknown
>   Source:6)
>           at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zaf.onConnected(Unknown
>   Source:2)
>           at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.BaseGmsClient$zzf.zzm(Unknown
>   Source:24)
>           at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.BaseGmsClient$zza.zza(Unknown
>   Source:12)
>           at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.BaseGmsClient$zzc.zzo(Unknown
>   Source:11)
>           at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.BaseGmsClient$zzb.handleMessage(Unknown
>   Source:48)
>           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
>           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>           at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)

my app/build.gradle

```
compile project(':react-native-maps')
compile project(':react-native-camera')
compile project(':react-native-linear-gradient')
compile project(':react-native-push-notification')
implementation (project(':react-native-camera')) {
  implementation "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0"
  implementation "com.facebook.react:react-native:+"  
}
implementation(project(':react-native-maps')){
   exclude group: 'com.google.android.gms', module: 'play-services-base'
   exclude group: 'com.google.android.gms', module: 'play-services-maps'
}
implementation ("com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:${rootProject.ext.googleFirebaseVersion}") {
    force = true
}
implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:${rootProject.ext.googlePlayServicesVersion}" 
implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:${rootProject.ext.googlePlayServicesVersion}"
implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:${rootProject.ext.googlePlayServicesVersion}"
implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-core:${rootProject.ext.googleFirebaseVersion}"
compile project(':instabug-reactnative')
compile project(':react-native-video')
compile project(':react-native-svg')
compile project(':react-native-picker')
compile project(':react-native-image-crop-picker')
compile project(':react-native-google-places')
compile project(':react-native-fast-image')
compile project(':react-native-exit-app')
compile project(':react-native-device-info')
implementation fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
implementation "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:${rootProject.ext.supportLibVersion}"
implementation "com.facebook.react:react-native:+"
```

Answer (score 1):

You must add `resolutionStrategy` to your app/build.gradle in `android` tag

```
android {
....
configurations.all {
            resolutionStrategy {
                force "com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:16.2.0"
            }
        }

...
}
```